# Using "Unite" to combine columns with partially matching names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using an online form to collect some data. When answering the questions the respondents can select one or more crops (as many as they like) and then add harvest related data. I ask this question twice (once     for grain yields and once for straw yields). For each crop they add, I get a new header name. I have limited control over how these columns are named by the software - I can't control the number, or its position in the sequence.

```
grain_yields.0.crop,
grain_yields.1.crop, 
grain_yields.2.crop, 
grain_yields.3.crop, 
grain_yields.4.crop,
...

straw_yields.0.crop,
straw_yields.1.crop, 
straw_yields.2.crop,
```

From this data I want to create two columns - one that pulls together all the types of crop for grain harvesting, and another for straw harvesting. This code does exactly what I want it to:

```
summary<- data.tidy %>%
    select(contains(starts_with("yields_required")|
           starts_with("grain_yields.") & ends_with(".crop")|
           starts_with("straw_yields.") & ends_with(".crop")) %>%
  unite(., col = "yields_required", matches("yields_required"), na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = " ") %>% 
  unite(., col = "farm_grain_yields_crop_type",  
        grain_yields.0.crop,
        grain_yields.1.crop, 
        grain_yields.2.crop, 
        grain_yields.3.crop, 
        grain_yields.4.crop, na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = ", ") %>%
  unite(., col = "farm_straw_yields_crop_type",  
        straw_yields.0.crop,
        straw_yields.1.crop, 
        straw_yields.2.crop, na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = ", ")
```

However, I want my code to be independent of the number of crops added so I can run it multiple times, as new answers come in. I have got this far:

```
summary<- data.tidy %>%
    select(starts_with("yields_required")|
           starts_with("grain_yields.") & ends_with(".crop")|
           starts_with("straw_yields.") & ends_with(".crop")) %>%
  unite(., col = "yields_required", matches("yields_required"), na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = ", ") %>% 
  unite(., col = "farm_grain_yields_crop", matches("grain_yields.|.crop"), na.rm=TRUE, remove = FALSE, sep = ", ") %>% 
  unite(., col = "farm_straw_yields_crop", matches("straw_yields.|.crop"), na.rm=TRUE, remove = FALSE, sep = ", ")
```

The problem is that unite() pulls the crop names from *both* ("grain_yields.|.crop") and ("straw_yields.|.crop"). When I change "remove" to TRUE then the column "farm_grain_yields_crop" gets deleted. I feel like I am going crazy because I can't see any obvious typos or errors, even after taking the night off and coming back in the morning, but this the output when I run the above code:

```
> summary
# A tibble: 19 x 11
   yields_required              farm_straw_yields_crop                             farm_grain_yields_crop          grain_yields.0.c~ grain_yields.1.c~ grain_yields.2.c~ grain_yields.3.c~ grain_yields.4.~ straw_yields.0.~ straw_yields.1.~ straw_yields.2.~
   <chr>                        <chr>                                              <chr>                           <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>             <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
 1 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
 2 Grain yields collected by t~ "winter wheat, winter barley, winter wheat, winte~ "winter wheat, winter barley, ~ winter wheat      winter barley     NA                NA                NA               winter wheat     winter barley    NA              
 3 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
 4 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
 5 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
 6 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
 7 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
 8 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
 9 Grain yields collected by t~ "winter wheat, winter wheat, winter wheat, winter~ "winter wheat, winter wheat"    winter wheat      NA                NA                NA                NA               winter wheat     NA               NA              
10 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
11 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
12 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
13 No yields required           ""                                                 ""                              NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
14 Grain yields collected by t~ "winter wheat, Winter Rye, winter barley, winter ~ "winter wheat, Winter Rye, win~ winter wheat      Winter Rye        winter barley     winter oats       Grass (Forage)   NA               NA               NA              
15 Grain yields collected by t~ "winter wheat, winter wheat"                       "winter wheat"                  winter wheat      NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
16 Grain yields collected by t~ "spring barley, spring barley, spring barley, spr~ "spring barley, spring barley"  spring barley     NA                NA                NA                NA               spring barley    NA               NA              
17 Grain yields collected by t~ "spring wheat, spring wheat"                       "spring wheat"                  spring wheat      NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
18 Grain yields collected by t~ "spring wheat, spring wheat"                       "spring wheat"                  spring wheat      NA                NA                NA                NA               NA               NA               NA              
19 Grain yields collected by t~ "winter wheat, winter oats, winter beans, winter ~ "winter wheat, winter oats, wi~ winter wheat      winter oats       winter beans      NA                NA               winter wheat     winter oats      winter beans
```

Thanks in advance for any advice, and apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Edit: I've realised my mistake is using the | operator which basically means "or" but I can't figure out how to use & or starts_with and ends_with.

Edit: I can't share the data.tidy because it inlcudes people's names, emails and phone numbers. If I remove the personal data then my data looks like this:

```
structure(list(yields_required.0 = c("No yields required", "Grain yields collected by the farm", 
"No yields required", "No yields required", "No yields required", 
"No yields required", "No yields required", "No yields required", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm", "No yields required", "No yields required", 
"No yields required", "No yields required", "Grain yields collected by the farm", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm", "Grain yields collected by the farm", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm", "Grain yields collected by the farm", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm"), yields_required.1 = c(NA, 
"Straw yields collected by the farm", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Straw yields collected by the farm", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Straw yields collected by the farm", NA, NA, "Straw yields collected by the farm"
), grain_yields.0.crop = c(NA, "winter wheat", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "winter wheat", NA, NA, NA, NA, "winter wheat", "winter wheat", 
"spring barley", "spring wheat", "spring wheat", "winter wheat"
), grain_yields.1.crop = c(NA, "winter barley", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Winter Rye", NA, NA, NA, NA, "winter oats"
), grain_yields.2.crop = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "winter barley", NA, NA, NA, NA, "winter beans"
), grain_yields.3.crop = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "winter oats", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), grain_yields.4.crop = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Grass (Forage)", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), straw_yields.0.crop = c(NA, "winter wheat", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "winter wheat", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"spring barley", NA, NA, "winter wheat"), straw_yields.1.crop = c(NA, 
"winter barley", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "winter oats"), straw_yields.2.crop = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "winter beans")), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

the output I want looks like this:

```
structure(list(yields_required = c("No yields required", "Grain yields collected by the farm Straw yields collected by the farm", 
"No yields required", "No yields required", "No yields required", 
"No yields required", "No yields required", "No yields required", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm Straw yields collected by the farm", 
"No yields required", "No yields required", "No yields required", 
"No yields required", "Grain yields collected by the farm", "Grain yields collected by the farm", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm Straw yields collected by the farm", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm", "Grain yields collected by the farm", 
"Grain yields collected by the farm Straw yields collected by the farm"
), farm_grain_yields_crop_type = c("", "winter wheat, winter barley", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "winter wheat", "", "", "", "", "winter wheat, Winter Rye, winter barley, winter oats, Grass (Forage)", 
"winter wheat", "spring barley", "spring wheat", "spring wheat", 
"winter wheat, winter oats, winter beans"), farm_straw_yields_crop_type = c("", 
"winter wheat, winter barley", "", "", "", "", "", "", "winter wheat", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "spring barley", "", "", "winter wheat, winter oats, winter beans"
)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The full list of data column names is:

```
c("proposal_number", "experiment_title", "first_name", "surname", 
"e_mail", "field.0", "harvest_year.0", "yields_required.0", "yields_required.1", 
"grain_yields.0.crop", "grain_yields.0.comments", "grain_yields.0.measurements.0", 
"grain_yields.0.measurements.1", "grain_yields.0.measurements.2", 
"grain_yields.0.measurements.3", "grain_yields.0.measurements.4", 
"grain_yields.0.number_plots", "grain_yields.0.number_replicates_per_plot", 
"grain_yields.0.sample_size", "grain_yields.1.crop", "grain_yields.1.measurements.0", 
"grain_yields.1.measurements.1", "grain_yields.1.measurements.2", 
"grain_yields.1.number_plots", "grain_yields.1.number_replicates_per_plot", 
"grain_yields.1.sample_size", "grain_yields.2.crop", "grain_yields.2.measurements.0", 
"grain_yields.2.measurements.1", "grain_yields.2.measurements.2", 
"grain_yields.2.number_plots", "grain_yields.2.number_replicates_per_plot", 
"grain_yields.2.sample_size", "grain_yields.3.crop", "grain_yields.3.measurements.0", 
"grain_yields.3.measurements.1", "grain_yields.3.measurements.2", 
"grain_yields.3.number_plots", "grain_yields.3.number_replicates_per_plot", 
"grain_yields.3.sample_size", "grain_yields.4.crop", "grain_yields.4.measurements.0", 
"grain_yields.4.measurements.1", "grain_yields.4.number_plots", 
"grain_yields.4.number_replicates_per_plot", "grain_yields.4.sample_size", 
"grain_handling_instructions", "straw_yields.0.crop", "straw_yields.0.measurements.0", 
"straw_yields.0.measurements.1", "straw_yields.0.measurements.2", 
"straw_yields.0.number_plots", "straw_yields.0.number_replicates_per_plot", 
"straw_yields.0.straw_yield_comments", "straw_yields.1.crop", 
"straw_yields.1.measurements.0", "straw_yields.1.measurements.1", 
"straw_yields.1.number_plots", "straw_yields.1.number_replicates_per_plot", 
"straw_yields.2.crop", "straw_yields.2.measurements.0", "straw_yields.2.measurements.1", 
"straw_yields.2.number_plots", "straw_yields.2.number_replicates_per_plot", 
"straw_handling_instructions", "pre_harvest_samples.0", "pre_harvest_measurements.0.comments", 
"pre_harvest_measurements.0.measruement", "post_harvest_samples.0", 
"post_harvest_sample_interval.0.duration", "post_harvest_sample_interval.0.number", 
"post_harvest_measurements.0.comments", "post_harvest_measurements.0.measruement", 
"notice_of_combining.0", "harvest_contacts.0.harvest_contact_comments", 
"harvest_contacts.0.harvest_contact_name", "harvest_contacts.0.havest_contact_mobile", 
"restricted_inputs.0", "crop_destruction.0", "obstructions.0", 
"obstructions_details", "special_instructions_notes
```

And the groups I am trying to create are

```
yields_required_[x]
grain_yields_[x]_crop
straw_yields_[x]_crop
grain_yields_[x]_measurements
straw_yields_[x]_measurements
```

Comment: Hi Aislinn, can you provide a sample of your data? `dput(head(data.tidy, 20)))`  should do it. Also, it might be helpful if you write your expected results to avoid any misunderstandings, as it is not always easy to really grasp what one wishes to achieve only by the description of the problem.

Comment: Hi Marcelo - I hope I've done that correctly. Sorry - I almost never post questions! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is now solved. If you want to unite two or more columns based on the start and end of the column names use:

```
unite(., col = "new name", starts_with("x") & ends_with("y"), na.rm=FALSE, remove = TRUE, sep = " ")
```

The above solution I worked through with Ronak Shah would work *IF* R gave you the option to suppress the duplicate column name error.

This is my full code, which I used for both selecting and uniting multiple columns in a tibble based on what the column names start and/or end with:

```
summary<- data.tidy %>%
    select(proposal_number, 
           experiment_title,
           first_name, 
         surname, 
         e_mail, 
         field.0, 
         harvest_year.0,
         contains("handling_instructions")|
         starts_with("yields_required")|
           starts_with("grain_yields.") & ends_with(".crop")|
           starts_with("straw_yields.") & ends_with(".crop")|
           starts_with("pre_harvest")|
           starts_with("post_harvest")|
           notice_of_combining.0,
           starts_with("harvest_contacts")|
           starts_with("restricted_inputs")|
           starts_with("crop_destruction")|
           special_instructions_notes) %>%
  unite(., col = "sponsor",  
        first_name,
        surname, na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = ", ") %>%
  unite(., col = "grain_yields_required", starts_with("grain_yields.") & ends_with(".crop"), na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = " ") %>%
  unite(., col = "straw_yields_required", starts_with("straw_yields.") & ends_with(".crop"), na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = " ") %>%
  unite(., col = "post-harvest_interval",  
        post_harvest_sample_interval.0.number,
        post_harvest_sample_interval.0.duration, na.rm=TRUE, remove = TRUE, sep = ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `split.default` to split similarly named columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.tidy %>%
  split.default(sub('\\..*', '', names(.))) %>%
  imap_dfc(~setNames(unite(.x, .y, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ', '), .y)) -> res

res

#   grain_yields                            straw_yields              yields_required                        
#   <chr>                                   <chr>                     <chr>                                  
# 1 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
# 2 "winter wheat, winter barley"           "winter wheat, winter ba… Grain yields collected by the farm, St…
# 3 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
# 4 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
# 5 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
# 6 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
# 7 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
# 8 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
# 9 "winter wheat"                          "winter wheat"            Grain yields collected by the farm, St…
#10 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
#11 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
#12 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
#13 ""                                      ""                        No yields required                     
#14 "winter wheat, Winter Rye, winter barl… ""                        Grain yields collected by the farm     
#15 "winter wheat"                          ""                        Grain yields collected by the farm     
#16 "spring barley"                         "spring barley"           Grain yields collected by the farm, St…
#17 "spring wheat"                          ""                        Grain yields collected by the farm     
#18 "spring wheat"                          ""                        Grain yields collected by the farm     
#19 "winter wheat, winter oats, winter bea… "winter wheat, winter oa… Grain yields collected by the farm, St…
```

Note that `sub` would give you common part in the column names dropping the `.` and number from the names.

```
sub('\\..*', '', names(data.tidy))
# [1] "yields_required" "yields_required" "grain_yields"    "grain_yields"    "grain_yields"   
# [6] "grain_yields"    "grain_yields"    "straw_yields"    "straw_yields"    "straw_yields"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Ronak. I was hoping to pipe the answer in if that is at all possible...?

Comment: Sure @AislinnPearson . Will the edited answer help ?

Comment: I just tried it and it almost worked! My other challenge is I have multiple columns that start with "grain_yields." that I didn't inlcude in the above. For example other column headings inlcude "grain.yields.0.comments" and "grain.yields.0.measurements". Ironically I didn't include them all in the example above because there are so many of them! But thanks for trying - your suggestion works if I split up the datasest. :)

Comment: Yes, basically you need to adapt the regex based on column names in your data and how you want to split them. For this you may use `sub('\\.\\d+', '', names(data.tidy))` and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah. It is very close to working, and that is definitely an improvement but it's still combining other columns I don't want it to... I may have to learn a bit more about regular expressions. I haven't used them before - maybe that is where my solution lies! I just need to find the right regular expresssion...

Comment: I can help with it if you provide all the column values using `dput(names(data.tidy))` and explain how do you want to make the groups.

Comment: That is incredibly kind of you @Ronak. I've been playing with it but not figured it out yet, so your help would be very welcome. I've added the information to the main post.

Comment: Here are couple of suggestions @AislinnPearson . First separate the columns that you want to divide. I think first few columns like `proposal_number`, `experiment_title`, `first_name` etc you don't want to be included in the group. So do something like `tmp <- data.tidy %>% select(-(proposal_number:email))`. Now apply the function only to `tmp` and use `gsub` instead of `sub` i.e `gsub('\\.\\d+', '', names(tmp))`. Once you get the output in `res` use `bind_cols` to add the columns which we removed earlier. `res <- data.tidy %>% select(proposal_number:email) %>% bind_cols(res)`

Comment: It's so close to working, the problem I am now having is that you cant use duplicate column names in a tibble. When I run this code: `summary <- data.tidy %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub('\\.\\d+', "", .x))` I get this error message: `Error: Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "yields_required" at locations 8 and 9.
  * "grain_yields.crop" at locations 10, 20, 27, 34, and 41.
  * "grain_yields.measurements" at locations 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, etc.` I tried using `summary <- data.tidy %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub('\\.\\d+', "", .x), check.names = FALSE)` but got the same error

Comment: Yes duplicate column names are not supported. But why are you using `rename_with` ? Why are you renaming columns here?

Comment: I had a similar problem when I tried using `bind_cols()`. Because the column names in `tmp` were the same, I got an error where R wouldn't recognise that the length of `tmp` was the same as that `res`. I was looking to find a way around it, which is how I ended up with `rename_with()`